# ContextMenu command binding doesn't work inside treeview hierarchicaldatatemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have a usercontrol and a viewmodel.

I have defined context menu inside **UserControl.Resources**

Context menu contains a menu item.I have set MenuItem header and command property.

**DeleteCommand** is defined in viewmodel. **I have also set datacontext property of MenuItem to usercontrol using RelativeSource**.

***[somehow this DataContext binding doesn't seems to be working]***

Inside user control I have treeview and its ItemSource is defined in viewmodel. TreeView has ParentNode and Child Node.

I am displaying context menu under child nodes only and to achieve this Treeview uses two **hierarchicaldatatemplate** **levelTemplate1** and **levelTemplate2**  to

When I right click on child node, I can see context menu but when I am clicking on **Delete**, OnExecute method for DeleteCommand is not firing.

Code structure is like:

```
     <UserControl.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="childContextMenu" >
        <MenuItem DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext}"
                  Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}"
                  Header="Delete"/>
    </ContextMenu>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="level2Template">
            <Grid ContextMenu="{StaticResource childContextMenu}">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding}"/>
            </Grid>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="level1Template"
                                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource level2Template}"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding childs}"
                                  >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>


        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" x:Key="TreeViewStyle">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <GroupBox Header="Tree" Grid.Column="0">
    <TreeView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource level1Template}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}"
              ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TreeViewStyle}">

    </TreeView>
    </GroupBox>
</Grid>
```

In output window it shows error

> "Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource
>   FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.UserControl',
>   AncestorLevel='1''

Comment: It would be awesome if you could simplify your problem done to a [mcve]

Comment: It sounds like there's an issue with your bindings, perhaps they cannot find the correct `DataContext`? I had a similar issue while trying to bind from within `UserControl.Resources`, please post some code to make your problem clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I changed **level2Template** as below and it detects the **Delete** command binding

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="level2Template">
                <Grid Tag="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeView}}">
                    <Grid.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                            <MenuItem Header="Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}"/>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Grid.ContextMenu>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding}">
                    </TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```